# On-screen 'widget' possible in tvOS?

Tags: ios, tvos

Would it be possible in tvOS to create a 'widget' type app that overlays a normal tv feed? Like a Live Score sports app that just sits at the bottom of the screen?

Is that do-able?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing as normal TV feed. Every content provider has his own app, which you cannot modify.